# appsettings.json in ASP.net Core 2.0 Preview configuration GetSection null

Tags: c#, json, configuration, .net-core

I was trying to call `GetSection` from injected configuration in the `Startup.cs`.
The Value was `null`, while `indexer` to a concrete section value returns `non-null` value. It seems to me a bug behind the `GetSection` method or I am wrong with it?

**appsettings.json:**

> {   "MyConfig": {
>       "ConfigA": "valueA",
>       "ConfigB": "valueB"   } }

**Program.cs:**

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = BuildWebHost(args);
        host.Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
```

**Startup.cs:**

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var mySection = this.Configuration.GetSection("MyConfig");

        var myVal = this.Configuration["MyConfig:ConfigA"];
```

Answer (score 12):

I first checked to see if there were any changes between [1.1.1](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/rel/1.1.1/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json/JsonConfigurationProvider.cs) and [2.x](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json/JsonConfigurationProvider.cs) of `JsonConfigurationProvider.cs`, the internal code that ultimately constructs retrievable values from your JSON file. There were no changes to this or any of the other code that ultimately gets called by your `this.Configuration.GetSection("MyConfig");`.

The way retrieving values works is that the `Configuration` will look for your key `MyConfig` in each config provider **in reverse order** as defined in code  until a value is found. In your example, providers (json, envionment variables, command line args) are provided within `Webhost.CreateDefaultBuilder()` [(see here)](https://github.com/aspnet/MetaPackages/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore/WebHost.cs#L161-L182).

Looking at the code for [JsonConfigurationFileParser.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json/JsonConfigurationFileParser.cs), it builds a `Dictionary<string, string>` for keys and values, *but only for primitive values*. That is, no key is stored for `MyConfig` (at this level it is an object), but there will be a key for `MyConfig:ConfigA`, and array values would look like `MyConfig:ConfigA:0`, `MyConfig:ConfigA:1`, etc.

Lastly, you will find that `Configuration.GetSection("MyConfig")` [always returns you a newly constructed](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration/ConfigurationRoot.cs#L104-L116) `ConfigurationSection` that is **never null**, and at the very worst will have a `Value` *property* of `null`.

So what happens when you hover over a `ConfigurationSection` with Intellisense and look at the `Value` property is that *every* config provider had been searched and none was found to have a key of "MyConfig" with a primitive value converted to string to return.

You will at the very least need to call:

```
services.Configure<MyConfigOptions>(configuration.GetSection("MyConfig"));
services.AddSingleton(cfg => cfg.GetService<IOptions<MyConfigOptions>>().Value);
```

to have it injected throughout your app as a C# object. Otherwise, call individual values with the colon `["MyConfig:ConfigA"]` separator syntax or with `var mySection = this.Configuration.GetSection("MyConfig")["ConfigA"];`, which is redundant but illustrates it is only used to retrieve primitives.

To bind to C# objects and inject them, I created the following extension method:

```
public static class IServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddConfigOptions<TOptions>(this IServiceCollection services,
        IConfiguration configuration, string section) where TOptions : class, new()
    {
        services.Configure<TOptions>(configuration.GetSection(section));
        services.AddSingleton(cfg => cfg.GetService<IOptions<TOptions>>().Value);
        return services;
    }
}
```

which can be called like this:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) => Configuration = configuration;

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddConfigOptions<EmailOptions>(Configuration, "Email")
```

and injected like this:

```
public class EmailSender : IEmailSender
{
    private EmailOptions _emailOptions;

    public EmailSender(EmailOptions options) => _emailOptions = options;
```

Comment: This works and in no way is this clear from the MS documentation.

Comment: That's because this goes against what Microsoft says to do. You should inject IOptions into your classes rather than trying to inject your configuration instance.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was missing a package:

`Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder`

It's in fact documented as a subtle code comment in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=basicconfiguration#getvalue)

Answer (score 0):

I found AspNetCore 2.0 to be so much simpler than 1.x in terms of configuration.

If you put a breakpoint in the `Startup(IConfiguration configuration)` constructor, you'll notice that the `configuration` variable has about 5 providers.

The `JsonConfigurationProvider` is the provider you're interested in for the *appsettings.json* file, but you will probably notice that the `Data` property has a `Count=0`. That is most likely due to the fact that your application is looking for the *appsettings.json* file in the directory specified in the `JsonConfigurationProvider.Source.FileProvider.Root` (which is by default wwwroot).

All I did was add an MSBuild task in the .csproj file as follows:

```
<Copy SourceFiles="appsettings.json" DestinationFolder="wwwroot" />
```

And that seemed to work perfectly.

This is obviously useful during ***local development only***. However, the general practice these days is never to have configuration in a file in the first place, especially since it will end up being part of your repo history. Instead, when deploying your app, the two common practices these days are using environment variables to override your values, or even better using a key/value store like consul.

Moreover, I see a whole bunch of fancy examples online on how to use the `services.Configure<>()` which is fine, but the `Startup.cs` already uses DI to inject values to `IConfiguration configuration`. That means that `IConfiguration` is already registered in .NET core's IoC Container, so that essentially means you can already use `IConfiguration` in any other class in your app like so:

```
public JobsRepository(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    this.configA = configuration.GetSection("MyConfig:ConfigA").Value;
}
```

Comment: You DO NOT ever want to copy appsettings.json to wwwroot. if you do so, you are making it publicly available(viewable). Why would you ever want to expose your configuration like that?

Comment: During startup it looks for appSettings.json in your WebRoot. This is obviously useful during _**local development only**_. However, the general practice these days is never to have configuration in a file in the first place, especially since it will end up being part of your repo history. Instead, when deploying your app, the two common practices these days are using environment variables to override your values, or even better using a key/value store like consul...

There is no need for negative voting without clarification first.

Comment: Even for local development, it should never go there. The file belongs in your /bin compiled output directory next to your other binaries. Aspnetcore will load it from there.