# How to access DB connectionstring in DAL from presentation layer

Tags: c#, connection-string, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I have .net core 2.0 Web API project with multiple layers i.e Presentation, BLL, DAL... I have my connection string in appsettings.json file which is present in Presentation layer. My DAL is responsible to get data from DB based on that connection string. How do I read that json file or pass connection string to DAL. 
P.S. Presentation layer depends on BLL and BLL depends on DAL.

> appsettings.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "Debug": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "Console": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MsSqlConnectionString": "Data Source=myServerName;Database=myDB;User Id=myUserID;Password=myPWd;"
  }
}
```

> DAL class

```
protected readonly string _connectionString;
protected IDbConnection _connection { get { return new SqlConnection(_connectionString); } }

public BaseDal()
{
    _connectionString = "<<How to get connectionstring from appsetting.json>>";
}
```

> ChildDAL

```
public class MyDAL : BaseDal, IMyDAL
{
    ILogger _log;
    public MyDAL(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _log = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("ChildDAL");
    }
    public async Task<IEnumerable<MyModel>> MyMethod(Dto criteria)
    {
        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();

        sql.Append("SELECT * FROM table");
        string query = sql.ToString();
        // custom mapping
        DapperCustomMapping<MyModel>();

        using (IDbConnection dbConnection = _connection)
        {
            return await dbConnection.QueryAsync<MyModel>(query);
        }
    }
}
```

> Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
             .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
             .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        //loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();
        loggerFactory.AddLog4Net();

        app.UseErrorWrappingMiddleware();
        app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/error/{0}");
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/error/500");

        // CORS: UseCors with CorsPolicyBuilder.
        app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");

        // MVC
        app.UseMvc();

        // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwagger();

        //Enable middleware to serve swagger - ui
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("../swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API v1");
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Read appsettings.json to get allowed origins
        var whiteList = new List<string>();
        var myArraySection = Configuration["AllowedOrigin"];
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(myArraySection))
        {
            foreach (var d in myArraySection.Split(','))
            {
                whiteList.Add(d.Trim());
            }
        }

        // CORS
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin",
                policy => policy.WithOrigins(whiteList.ToArray()));
        });

        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            // install global fitler on all controllers and actions.
            options.Filters.Add(new CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory("AllowSpecificOrigin"));
            options.Filters.Add(new ValidateModelAttribute());
        })
        // tell how to find the fluent validations
        .AddFluentValidation(fv => fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<ContactQueryDtoValidator>());

        // Register the Swagger generator
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "API", Version = "v1" });
        });

        return ConfigureIoC(services);
    }

    public IServiceProvider ConfigureIoC(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var container = new Container();
        container.Configure(config =>
        {
            config.Scan(_ =>
            {
                _.AssemblyContainingType(typeof(Startup)); // web api
                _.AssemblyContainingType(typeof(HelloBLL)); // Unused BLL
                _.AssemblyContainingType(typeof(HelloDAL)); // Unused DAL
                _.TheCallingAssembly();
                _.WithDefaultConventions();

            });

            config.Populate(services);
        });
        return container.GetInstance<IServiceProvider>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45030383/appsettings-json-in-asp-net-core-2-0-preview-configuration-getsection-null?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Where is the connection string passed to DAL?

Comment: How are you creating instances of `BaseDal`?

Comment: @KirkLarkin Here comes the right question. I am inheriting BaseDAL. See my updated question

Comment: Are you registering `MyDAL` with DI? If so, can you include the code so I can give an example solution?

Comment: @KirkLarkin Added my startup.cs class

Comment: You're going to need a solution similar to what @Manoj proposes - Pass the `IOptions<T>` into your `MyDAL` constructor and pass it on to its base, `BaseDal`. Another option is to override the DI registration and provide the `connectionString` value itself to the constructor. I'm not familiar with StructureMap, so will not attempt to give code.

Answer (score 1):

Another method to access the Configuration File, referenced from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=basicconfiguration

Make sure you import the libraries below

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System.IO;

    public BaseDal()
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

        Configuration = builder.Build();
        var _connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("CONNECTION_STRING")
    }
```

Comment: Error:The name 'Configuration' does not exist in the current context. Then after importing System.Configuration I get error: The type or namespace name 'GetConnectionString' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Configuration' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: My mistake, if you look in your startup.cs class you'll find a Configuration field which you can use to reference your appsettings.json file.

Comment: its using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration. After using that I get Configuration as null and then object ref not set error. 
`public IConfigurationRoot Configuration; 
protected readonly string _connectionString;
_connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("MsSqlConnectionString");`

Comment: Can't go wrong with the next option, I don't know of a clean way to reference the connection string.

Comment: NP! Thanks for looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have registered the section in startup.cs file of presentation layer.

```
  public class AppSettings
    {
        public string MsSqlConnectionString{ get; set; }
    }

   //registering in ConfigureServices method of Startup.cs
   services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings"));
```

To access in DAL layer simillarly you would have to create `AppSettings` class there also and then simply use

```
public BaseDal(IOptions<AppSettings> app)
{
    _connectionString = app.Value.MsSqlConnectionString;;
}
```

**Edit**

When you receive

> Error: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required
>   formal parameter 'app' of 'BaseDal.BaseDal(IOptions)'

that means you are not giving it required parameter. You can call the base class and give `required` parameter by calling `:base(parameters...)` constructor.

```
public class MyDAL : BaseDal, IMyDAL
{
    ILogger _log;
    public MyDAL(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,IOptions<AppSettings> app):base(app)
    {
        _log = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("ChildDAL");
    }
}
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that earlier. I have multiple child class inherited from BaseDAL so if I add parameterized constructor I get bunch of errors from child classes to pass that parameter. 
Error: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'app' of 'BaseDal.BaseDal(IOptions<AppSettings>)'